# Background color of button not showing up after using control template in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, controltemplate

> Beginner question here.
>
> I have a button whose Background is bound to a property in my 
>   ViewModel. The same button also has a command whose implementation is
>   in my ViewModel. The clicking toggles a boolean in my VM & that
>   changes both the text & color of that button. All good so far, but
>   when my mouse hovers over, I get this blue color to remove which I
>   have a control template in my Style. Problem is now upon button click,
>   only text changes, no background change & no mouse over change.  Following is my Button definition

```
<Button  x:Name="OnlineBtn"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="206,6,10,10"  
                        Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="41"                   
                        Command="{Binding Path=OnlineCommand}"
                        Background="{Binding OnlineButtonProp,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                         Style="{StaticResource OnLineButtonStyle}">
```

And below is my Control Template definition.

```
 <Style x:Key="OnLineButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">                
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>                                   
                            </Trigger>            
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">                                
                        </ContentPresenter>    
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have seen the example on SO about how to set this control template, but my question is kinda two fold
1) Why is my IsMouseOver property not working
2) Why are my background color Button property that has bound props in my VM not working

The IsMouseOver Setter background is chosen RED just for testing the impact of the mouse over.

Comment: As a note, setting Mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the Background Binding is pointless. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a Background explicitly (as done with your Binding) has higher [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) than the Setter in the Trigger. Hence the Trigger is ignored.

You should add an element like Border or Grid to your ControlTemplate where you set the Background with a TemplateBinding to the Button's Background. Then make the Trigger change that element's Background instead of the Button Background:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, but I would like to leave the button property bnindings as is to its VM properties, and change the IsMouseOver prop to where the hovering over the button shouldn't change the button background color & text. Is that possible? If so, can you guide me

Comment: You didn't try what I've posted? Of course you can leave the Button Bindings as is, just fix the Template.

Comment: Ok.. I did try and the IsMouseOver does work .Now what do I set the IsMouseOver Value to so as to not see any change in color owing to the mouse over the button?

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question... Remove the Trigger.